# When I runBundle update, I get a (SyntaxError) after setting up a new rails app? Why is this happening

Tags: rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2, bundle, bundler, railstutorial.org

I'm a Rails Newbie, I'm doing the Hartl Rails Tutorial and installed with Railsinstaller

C:\Sites\sample_app>bundle update

C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/
dsl.rb:7:in `instance_eval': C:/Sites/sample_app/Gemfile:43: syntax error, unexp
ected $end, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:7:in`evaluate'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/definition.rb:17:in `build'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler.rb:138:in`definition'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/cli.rb:262:in `update'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in`run'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:263:in`dispatch'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:386:in `start'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/bin/bundle:13:in`'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/bundle:19:in`'

This is my gemfile.  It looks correct but I just don't know what the bundle install is error'ing out.

```
Source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.12'

group :development, :test do
gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.5'
gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'
gem 'rb-readline'

group :test do
gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
end

group :production do
gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

Comment: What exactly is the question?! You will probably need to provide more details before someone can help.

Comment: @dvelopment please post your Gemfile here.

Answer (score 0):

The group for development and test where you load the sqlite3 gem is never ended. It should probably be this:

```
group :development, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
    gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
end
```

Comment: Thanks that worked great! I'm a Newbie, but I still can't believe I missed that.

Comment: @dvelopment You're welcome. :) If this answer resolved your problem, you should mark it as the answer so the question is shown to be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You havent closed the group for `test, development` and `assets` as well. You need to close them like :

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
  gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'
  gem 'rb-readline'
end
```

PS : Try to keep your code indented. It helps to find out the unclosed tags just by having a glance on the file. :)